# How To Use MySQL Indexes Properly?

Tags: mysql

I'm using php and MySQL with a rather large MySQL database and I am trying to use idexes for the first time. I get the concept that the server will look through the index first but I'm moving trouble getting the server to use the index. So my questions are:

Does having a primary key (thus primary index?) in the table get used over the index I'm trying to use from another column? Do I have to explicitly specify the index in the select query? (I'm using several table joins, btw)

Does anyone know of a good beginners guide to using MySQL indexes? I haven't found a good one!

Comment: You indexed the columns which will be used more frequently in the where clause, mysql optimizer does the rest.

Comment: There's an O'Reilly book, High Performance MySQL, that's pretty good.  Also this blog: http://www.percona.com/blog/

Comment: Your indexes should best match the columns you are using in your joins. One important rule with mysql is that the index fields can only be used in order, IE if your index is a,b,c and you join on c or b without a or c without a and b then mysql cannot use the index.

Comment: @Giles can you clarify that comment, (possibly as an answer?) as it took  me several reads to understand the i.e part... cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important rule for mysql indexes, say you have the following index:

```
KEY(A,B,C)
```

Then in your code you have a where clause or join such as:

```
WHERE B = 'mydata' AND C = 'moredata'
```

Mysql will not be able to make use of the index for the query because the indexes work in the order given and the column A has not been included.
The fix is to either use A in the query or re-order the index (or add a second index) as so:

```
KEY(C,B,A)
```

or (if you don`t need A at all in the WHERE/JOIN):

```
KEY(C,B)
```

Also check out [explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) which should help you find why your indexes are not being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One question, so by Key(A,B,C) do you mean one index using columns A, B, and C? Or do you mean three separate indexes on columns A, B, and C respectively?  Also, does adding a primary key automatically add an index?  Meaning, if it is not useful to me should I just delete it?

Comment: Sorry for the slow answer, I was away. Yes, I meant one key with the 3 columns. Key and Index are synonyms so a key is an index (and a primary key is a unique index). A unique index defines a constraint on the table, so best leave it in place. Other indexes - if you know you, and no-one else, is using the index in their queries, then deleting the index will save on storage.